# Convert string to ISODate

Tags: javascript, date

How could I convert the string `"2015-02-02"` to ISODate `2015-02-02T00:00:00.000Z`? I was trying to find some example but did not.

Comment: Have you considered `'2015-02-02' + 'T00:00:00.000Z'`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the regular Javascript date functionality for this

```
new Date(dateString).toISOString()
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

However, date parsing is very inconsistent across browsers so if you need this to be robust I would look into parsing using for example with Moment.js as this will allow you to specify a format string by which the date should be parsed like such

```
date = moment("12-25-1995", "YYYY-MM-DD");
date.format(); //will return an ISO representation of the date
```

from: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: @Ok thanks. Could you also please update how to convert back from ISODate? :)

Comment: that would be
moment(datestring, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ

Comment: Without moment I would just use new Date(datestring) as I think all browsers will understand an ISO date format

Comment: Back to string I meant:)

Comment: Ah i'm sorry. In that case you would either have to write a function that splits the iso date string and parses it to the format you want, or use the toLocaleFormat function specified herer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat although that is only supported in firefox I believe

Comment: No, don't do that. Some browsers will treat it as UTC, some as local and some invalid.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date("2015-02-02").toISOString()
```

Answer (score 2):

To change "2015-02-02" to "2015-02-02T00:00:00.000Z" simply append "T00:00:00.000Z":

```
console.log('2015-02-02' + 'T00:00:00.000Z');
```

Parsing to a Date and calling *toISOString* will fail in browsers that don't correctly parse ISO dates and those that don't have *toISOString*.

Comment: Another down-voter without the courage of their convictions to say why they down voted. I simply don't see the point of parsing a string to a date, then calling a method to get back exactly the same string with a fixed, known extension (and typing 7 extra characters in the process) and apparently the downvoter doesn't have a counter argument worth expressing. :-(

Answer (score -1):

```
new Date("11/11/2019").toISOString()
```

or use it as a variable

```
mydate = "11/11/2019"
new Date(mydate).toISOString()
```